# Why i cannot access computer with apache on it via 'connectify hotspot' on same computer?

Tags: apache-2.2, iphone, wlan, wifi

This is the situation:

- Computer running Windows XP
- Running Apache
- LAN: Internet connection
- WLAN (Wi-Fi): Hotspot with Connectify software (http://www.connectify.me/), FREE version
- iPhone 3G connected to computers WLAN to share computer internet connection

So far, the internet connection (browsing the internet) is working fine. When i use the computers IP address (for example: http://192.0.2.1/examplefolder/) to access the server that is running on the computer it cannot connect on the iPhone (timeout). When SOMEBODY else (i don't have two computers) do the same on another computer it is working fine and you see a webpage.

Can somebody explain why it is not working via the hotspot, i know already that it has something to do with the hotspot connection because my computer is visible thru the internet. But why, can anybody explain that to me? Is there a solution to this?

I use this configuration to test websites on an iPhone. I don't have a 3G internet connection available on the iPhone so i want to do it this way.

Comment: Ah, digg me with -1, explain to me why.

Comment: "-1" for: 1. You are not a sysadmin. 2. This situation is so hacked together there might be a million reasons why it's not working. Mostly #2. Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] before posting again.

Comment: Ah, that is not nice. To access resources you need passwords,so what is wrong with it. A hotspot is nothing new and in this situation it is the only way to do it.

Comment: Why is it not a real question, i don't get it, @Alex gives me hint to the right direction. Chris is what it profile says (first lines). Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Chris mentioned, you lack most of what is needed to help you.

Apache configuration for starter would be a must. Finding Apache Logs would also be a good place to start.

You claim that the HotSpot is the cause of your problem when it could actually be your Apache configuration. It can also be your Windows Firewall configuration.

Anyway, I would have a look at the Apache configuration and make sure that the server's [Listen configuration](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) is properly setup.

You might have it setup to listen on its LAN IP only and therefore dropping request from your Wi-Fi NIC.

In your case I assume it would look like this:

> Listen 192.168.2.1:80

If that's the case, and your phone is reaching Apache by using another IP, then Apache will not answer.

Comment: Hey thanks guy, it took me to the solution. It seems that Apache is not immediately detect new network cards, restarting apache is the solution! Apache listen to all cards on port 80 (listen 80). The networkcard must have an IP address, they must be started before Apache. Since my wireless network is not always turned on (because of security) i ha ve to restart apache. Thanks for the tip!